# How get object's method by string in twig

Tags: twig

In php I can get object method as:

```
$methodName="getId";
$obj->{$methodName}();
```

Is there such features in twig?

**UPD:** I would like some as :

```
{% set method='getId' %}
{{ obj[method]() }}
```

Now I use extention:

```
{{ getter(obj, method) }}
```

But maybe  is there a standard solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard solution does exist, similar to your extension:

```
{{ attribute(obj, method) }}
```